# Tag [vs-2019] should be a synonym for [visual-studio-2019]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

I recently noticed the tag [vs-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-2019) being used even though we already have [visual-studio-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2019). The former doesn't have tag wiki, so it looks like someone created it by mistake. I believe it should be a synonym for the latter or removed altogether.

I checked and found out that we already have [vs-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-2013) as a synonym for [visual-studio-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013) and [vs-2015-preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-2015-preview) as a synonym of [visual-studio-2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015) so I think we should do the same here. I wasn't able to directly propose a synonym request because I don't have a sufficient score in the tag.

Comment: Agree on this. With 48 questions not really something we want to re-tag by hand. I quickly scanned the list and all questions seem to be about visual studio 2019. If you find a question that isn't about vs-2019, it is better re-tagged now. If a mod on duty comes by they can proceed ...

Comment: If only there was a moderator who used this tool almost daily and knew what to do... Oh, hey, we're in luck! Cleaned up some other loose ends surrounding Visual Studio-related tags while I was at it, too. If you see any that I missed, lemme know.

Comment: @CodyGray That was quick. Great job!