# Make [vs2019] a synonym for [visual-studio-2019]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Pretty straight-forward and obvious request.

Today, I stumbled on [vs2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2019) in the new tags tool. I quickly retagged the single question with [visual-studio-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2019).

I now see that a new question already popped-up with [vs2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2019) and I'm guessing that it's going to be a rat-race trying to retag it every time. Similar to virtually all other VS versions (see [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2010/synonyms), [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2012/synonyms), [2013](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2013/synonyms), ..., [2017](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2017/synonyms)), can we make it a synonym?

I'm guessing this is already a solid request, but just to further support it - a synonym [vs-2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-2019) [already exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397740/6045800) and this one is basically a typo version of it...

Comment: Why keep the `vs2019` tag when we have [tag:visual-studio-2019]

Comment: @PCM Because most likely people will keep using (creating) it. So as I mentioned in my question, instead of eternally chasing and retagging them, I'm offering to make it a synonym so the problem is solved. If you are not familiar with the concept of synonyms, read about them in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)

Comment: Yeah, this is a textbook synonym case. I don't see there being any concerns or opposition here.